# Обновление вложенного словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Есть `dict`, например:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 'e': 'ref:a.b.c'}}
```

ключ **`e`** - это путь (ключей словаря) для замены на значение из этого же словаря.

В итоге должен получиться словарь:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 'e': {'d': 1}}}
```

Есть ли встроенные модули для решения такой задачи или как создать функцию (или метод), который изменяет переданный словарь или возвращает новый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я тоже не вполне уверен, что правильно понял ваши пожелания, но, в принципе получить нужный результат можно так:

```
dct = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 
             'e': 'ref:a.b.c'}}

path = dct['a']['e'].strip('ref:').split('.')
dct['a']['e'] = (f:= lambda x,y: x if not y else f(x[y.pop(0)],y))(dct,path)

print(dct)  # {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 'e': {'d': 1}}}
```

**UPD**

если суть вопроса в том, чтобы сначала найти все ссылки, а потом сделать соответствующие замены, то вот такой метод вроде дает нужный результат:

```
class Ref:
    
    def __call__(self, _dict):
        self._dict = _dict
        self.search(self._dict)
        return self._dict
        
    def search(self, d):  # ищем ссылки
        for k in d:
            if type(d[k])==dict: self.search(d[k])
            if type(d[k])==str and d[k][:4]=='ref:':
                d[k] = self.sub(d[k][4:].split('.'), self._dict)
            
    def sub(self, to_sub, dct):  # заменяем ссылки на значения, полученные по ссылкам
        if not to_sub: return dct
        return self.sub(to_sub, dct[to_sub.pop(0)])
```

ввод:

```
dict_to_sub = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1},
                           'h': {'i': 2}}, 
               'e': 'ref:a.b.c',
               'f': 'ref:a.b.h'}}
sub_ref = Ref()
sub_ref(dict_to_sub)
```

вывод:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}, 'h': {'i': 2}}, 'e': {'d': 1}, 'f': {'i': 2}}}
```

Comment: Да, наверное не совсем правильно/подробно описал задачу. Нужно именно универсальное решение, где, например, словарь может быть любой вложенности и с любым количеством "ref:", с различными типами данных, и, например, ситуация, когда ссылки ссылаются на ссылки. Ваш вариант (после обновления) я протестировал с различными подобными вариациями, вроде все работает. К тому же оформлен как класс, и достаточно лаконичный. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Если делать нечто более-менее универсальное, то предлагаю для определения ссылки завести отдельный класс для более наглядного хранения и лёгкого обнаружения. Тогда требуемый функционал можно реализовать как-то так:

```
class Ref:
    def __init__(self, path):
        if isinstance(path, list):
            self.path = '.'.join(path)
        else:
            self.path = path
    def get_path(self):
        return self.path

def dict_get_by_path(d:dict, key:str, default=None):
    def get_one_level(d, key_list, level=0):
        if level < len(key_list)-1:
            return get_one_level(d[key_list[level]], key_list, level+1)
        elif level == len(key_list)-1:
            return d[key_list[level]]
        raise IndexError

    try:
        return get_one_level(d, key.split('.'))
    except KeyError:
        return default

def replace_refs(d, sub_d=None):
    if sub_d is None: sub_d = d
    for k,v in sub_d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            replace_refs(d, v)
        elif isinstance(v, Ref):
            sub_d[k] = dict_get_by_path(d, v.get_path())
        
d = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 'e': Ref('a.b.c')}}
replace_refs(d)
print(d)
```

Где `dict_get_by_path()` - функция, которая достает значение из словаря по пути вида `"a.b.c"`. А `replace_refs()` рекурсивно проходит по всем элементам словаря и при обнаружении ссылок `Ref` заменяет их на значения по ссылкам.

Если очень хочется без отдельного класса, то вместо

```
        elif isinstance(v, Ref):
            sub_d[k] = dict_get_by_path(d, v.get_path())
```

можно написать

```
        elif isinstance(v, str) and v.startswith('ref:'):
            sub_d[k] = dict_get_by_path(d, v[4:])
```

Comment: Хороший вариант. Класс здорово использовать, если структура только Python, но, если, например, читать json или yaml, то он уже не подходит.

Answer (score 2):

Предложу свой вариант универсального решения. Используем две функции. Первая `find()` для поиска значения по указанному пути, организованная через `reduce` и `operator.getitem`. Вторая `dict_refresh` проходит рекурсивно словарь в поисках ссылки. Как только находит ее, то через `find()` подставляем значение по ссылке. Если такой ссылки нет, то будет замена на `None`.

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def find(d, path):
    try:
        return reduce(operator.getitem, path.split('.'), d)
    except KeyError:
        return None

def dict_refresh(d, d_init=None):
    for k in d:
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            dict_refresh(d[k], d_init or d)
        if isinstance(d[k], str) and d[k].startswith('ref:'):
            d[k] = find(d_init, d[k].replace('ref:', ''))

d = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 'e': {'f': 'ref:a.b.c'}}}
dict_refresh(d)
print(d)
# {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 'e': {'d': 1}}}
```

Для комментария **GrAnd**:

```
d = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 'e': {'f': 'ref:a.b.c'}}}
dict_refresh(d)
print(d)
# {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 'e': {'f': {'d': 1}}}}
```

Comment: А в таком словаре `{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 'e': {'f': 'ref:a.b.c'}}}` заменит на `None`.

Comment: Да, у меня в конце об этом написано. Ссылка же есть. Значит на нее нужно что-то подать.

Comment: Так дело в том, что ссылка та же, и она валидна.

Comment: А! Спасибо. Поправил ответ. Не понял сначала вопроса.

Comment: О! Я теперь понял, почему ваш первый ответ тоже ввёл меня в небольшое замешательство. :) Да, действительно, если в конце моего первого сообщения поставить вопросительный знак, то ваш ответ звучит логично. Но вот загвоздка, моё первое сообщение было утверждением, а не вопросом. :D

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за комментарий. Так понял, что не до конца пробрасываю через рекурсию исходный словарь.

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, что правильно вас понял, но попробуйте так:

```
_dict = {
    'a': {
        'b': {
            'c': {'d': 1}
        }, 
        'e': 'ref:a.b.c'
    }
}
print(_dict)

ref = _dict['a']['e'][4:].split('.')

d = _dict
for k in ref:
    d = d[k]
new_ref = d    

_dict['a']['e'] = new_ref
print(_dict)
```

Comment: Ну, это не совсем универсальное решение. Словарь может быть любой вложенности и с любым количеством "ref:", с различными типами данных, и, например, ситуация, когда ссылки ссылаются на ссылки. Наверное не совсем правильно/подробно описал задачу (

Answer (score 1):

```
def changer(origin, link={}):
    if not link:
        link = origin
    for key, value in link.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            changer(origin, value)
            continue
        if (isinstance(value, str)) and ('ref' in value):
            tmp = origin
            for way in value.split(':')[1].split('.'):
                tmp = tmp[way]
            link[key] = tmp

    return origin


print(changer({'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 'e': 'ref:a.b.c'}}))
# {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 1}}, 'e': {'d': 1}}}
```

Comment: Бесконечная рекурсия для варианта `changer({'a': {}})`. А также будет попытка сделать замену для варианта `changer({'a': 'This is not a reference.'})`.

Comment: Самый лаконичный вариант, только что бесконечная рекурсия все портит) Нужно просто доработать этот код немного